# Creating unique index in mongo DB with certain condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to mongodb. While researching on the topic "imposing unique constraints in mongodb" i came across the concept of createindex with unique field set to true. This ensures that a certain field on which the index is created becomes unique throughout the DB.

I have a Student collection which has three field: student_id, name, age. I want student_id to be unique throughout my DB. Now , for the value of field 'name' = "XYZ" , i can allow many record where the student_id need not be unique. For all other  value of 'name' the student_id has to be unique.

For example: if the content of initial student collection is:

```
[
  { "student_id": 1 
    "name": "A",
    "age": 1.0
  },
  { 
    "student_id": 2 
    "name": "B",
    "age": 2.0
  }
]
```

Now , if i want to insert record

```
{ 
  "student_id": 2 
  "name": "C",
  "age": 105.0
}
```

it should tell me that `student_id: 2` already exists(or Duplicate entry).
But if i want to insert record:

```
{ 
  "student_id": 2 
  "name": "XYZ",
  "age": 105.0
}
```

it should allow me to insert since i want to insert any record, if `name: "XYZ"` for any value of student_id.
For all other name value i want student_id field to be unique.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciable. Thanks .

Comment: Ah, turns out, you can't use negated expressions ("not XYZ") in partial index expressions. A pity. Otherwise, it would have helped you.

Comment: Yeah exactly. Anyway Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a unique index on two keys, In your case create a unique index on name and student_id. This will resolve your case.
Check the link for more help: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/

Comment: No i guess. I do not want to impose the constraints on the 'name' field. There can be multiple record which can have the same name . What i exactly want is : For a given value of name , there can be multiple student_id possible. In continuation to my previous example, there can be many student_id possible for the name 'XYZ' . But a single student_id should not map to multiple names other than 'XYZ'. That is, for student_id : 1, there can not be two record having different names as : name:'ABC', and another record having student_id:1 and name as 'DEF'.

Comment: On what I have understood may be a trick here, you can use _id of mongoDB as student id. Therefore this will never get duplicated nor remain null. Hope this helps.

Comment: No, This contradicts to my requirement. if i make _id of mongoDB as student_id and do one to one mapping of them , I will not be able to insert the second record where student_id=2 and name = 'XYZ'. Requirement is to have duplicate student_id when name ='XYZ'.